# IDA's debuggers disappeared

Tags: ida, debuggers

Using IDA 7

I've been debugging a program with remote GDB just fine. Today when I opened the database, most of the debuggers are missing from the list, including GDB. It's only when opening this database, though. Any ideas?

[image: list of debuggers]

Comment: Your database contains executable that runs on x86/x64 ?